# Como retirar opções padrões do Google Maps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Pessoal tenho uma dúvida, estou criando um aplicativo que utiliza o Google Maps V2, tem como REMOVER essas opções padrões do Mapa ? Isso acontece quando clico no marcador e automaticamente surgem essas duas opções padrões dele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode incluir o código de criação? Olhando a API basta usar o método `setMapToolbarEnabled` passando `false` no seu objeto `UiSettings` relativo ao mapa que está usando.

Comment: Valeu Wakim, é isso mesmo só precisei botar o setMapToolbarEnabled como false e sumiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para remover esses dois botões bastar desabilitar o `MapToolbar` usando:

```
GoogleMap map = ...;
map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Mais informações: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_toolbar